# cypher query to calculate percent of total cost for each component in a hierarchy

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a bill of materials dataset.

```
   *data model*
    (:part)
       -part_num
       -cost

    [:component_of]
       -quantity
```

The following query will create a full BOM hierarchy properly

```
MATCH path=(p:part)-[r:component_of*0..]->(fg:part)
WHERE fg.part_num = 'D100'
RETURN path
```

To support a cost visualization, I am trying to calculate the percent cost attributed to the finished good (fg:part) by each component part. The logic I want to implement is as follows.

example path:

(a:part)-[:component_of]->(b:part)-[:component_of]->(fg:part)

1. for each part calculate the percent of its cost for its parent part. pct = (part.cost * relationship.quantity) / parent_part.cost
2. go back through the hierarchy and determine the effective percent cost. If (a) is 50% of the cost of (b), and (b) is 25% of the cost of (fg) then the effective percent cost of (a) is .5 * .25 = .125 or 12.5%.

Is this something that can be done in a cypher query? Where would I begin?

Comment: This is probably going to be even more complicated than the 2 steps you provided. In general, any part (say, a screw) could be in multiple subcomponents. So, you'd have to be able to produce a correct percentage for any part that appears in multiple places in the hierarchy.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `reduce` function:

```
MATCH path=(p:part)-[r:component_of*0..]->(fg:part)
WHERE fg.part_num = 'D100'
WITH path, 
     NODES(path) AS nds, 
     RELATIONSHIPS(path) AS rls
RETURN path, 
       REDUCE(acc=1.0, i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(path)-1) | 
              0.0001 * acc * nds[i].cost*rls[i].quantity / nds[i+1].cost
       ) AS epc
```